# How to define a TikZ style for a `matrix of node keys`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to define a style `matrix of node keys` such that

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzpicture
\matrix [matrix of node keys]
  {red,node contents=a & blue,node contents=b \\};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

compiles to the same result as

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzpicture
\matrix [matrix of nodes]
  {|[red]|a & |[blue]|b \\};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

I am now studying `tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex`: it seems to me that the bulk of the code is devoted to parsing the optional syntax. Since I need nothing of that, there might be a smarter way to do what I want. In fact, the example from the manual implementing an essential version of the `matrix` library is just

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [matrix of nodes/.style={
    execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup,
    execute at end cell=\egroup;%
  }]
  \matrix [matrix of nodes]
  {
    8 & 1 & 6 \\
    3 & 5 & 7 \\
    4 & 9 & 2 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

An utterly naive attempt could be

```
\input tikz
\let\bsquare[
\let\esquare]
\tikzpicture[matrix of node keys/.style={
  execute at begin cell=\node\bsquare,
  execute at end cell=\esquare;,
}]
\matrix [matrix of node keys]
  {red,node contents=a & blue,node contents=b \\};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

but it fails because the use of `\tikz@fig@scan@options` mismatches its definition (it expects the form `[#1]`).

**What is the safest and soundest way to define `matrix of node keys`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{matrix of node keys/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{
        matrix,%
        cells={anchor=base},%
        execute at begin cell=\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell,
        execute at empty cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell
    }
}}

\bgroup
\catcode`&=\active
\gdef\monk@nil{\pgfutil@gobble{unique expansion text}}
    \gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@slsl{
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil
        {\expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow\pgfutil@gobble}
        {\pgfmatrixendrow}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell{
    \let\\\matrix@ofnodekeys@slsl
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\relax{}{\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@#1\\{
    %\def\temp{#1}\show\temp
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil
        {\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@ #1\\}
        {\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@ #1&\monk@nil\\\monk@nil}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@#1&{
  \node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,#1]{};
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil{\pgfutil@gobble}{&}
}
\egroup
\makeatother
```

And here's a fully plain TeX example (using `pgfutil` macros isn't strictly necessary):

```
\input tikz

\catcode`@=11 %\makeatletter

\tikzset{matrix of node keys/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{
        matrix,%
        cells={anchor=base},%
        execute at begin cell=\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell,
        execute at empty cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell
    }
}}

\bgroup
\catcode`&=\active
\gdef\monk@nil{\pgfutil@gobble{unique expansion text}}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@slsl{
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil
        {\expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow\pgfutil@gobble}
        {\pgfmatrixendrow}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell{
    \let\\\matrix@ofnodekeys@slsl
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\relax{}{\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@#1\\{
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil
        {\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@ #1\\}
        {\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@ #1&\monk@nil\\\monk@nil}
}
\gdef\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell@@#1&{
  \node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,#1]{};
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\monk@nil{\pgfutil@gobble}{&}
}
\egroup  
\catcode`@=12 %\makeatother

\tikzpicture [
  every odd row/.style={red},
  every even column/.style={font=\bf}
]
\matrix [matrix of node keys] {
  node contents=a & node contents=b & fill=orange,node contents=c \\
  blue,node contents=d & rectangle,draw,node contents=e & magenta,node contents=f \\
  rotate=60,node contents=g & node contents=h & node contents=i \\
};
\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

The output:

[image: ecce matrix]

Comment: This is great. I thought that a Plain TeX MWE wouldn't have elicited a LaTeX solution (I'd like to have maximal portability) but since the only LaTeX macro you have used is `\@ifnextchar` I think replacing it with PGF's internal `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` is sufficient to make it completely format agnostic. However, I am not sure I understood how this style works. I think you are parsing the whole lines from the relative first cell start, recursing calls to tread the columns and using `\@nil` as the row terminator while inserting back the correct row/line separators. [continues...]

Comment: [...continued] At this point you have a correctly formatted matrix of `\nodes`, and the lower level parsing is done so the internals you used (keeping the cell indices) *just* work. Also, because of this the global styles for specific parts (like e.g. `every odd row`) keep working perfectly (I was really happy noticing this). Is this, more or less, how it works? Is this how the usual `matrix of nodes` also works?

Comment: Yeah sorry, there's nothing LaTeX specific about it, I just didn't notice that detail. Your description of how it works is exactly right.

Comment: The only extra detail worth mentioning is that normally `\\ ` is `\let` to `\pgfmatrixendrow`, but in this case my code inserts a `\@nil` after the last `\\ ` to make sure that it doesn't keep inserting more terminal `&\@nil`'s. But `\pgfmatrixendrow` checks if the next character is an end brace and uses that to decide when to quit. Without changing the value of `\\ `, `\pgfmatrixendrow` checks what the next character is and sees my `\@nil`, and decides to start a new cell. This generates an "error missing close brace" because it never ends the matrix.

Comment: This is not how the usual `matrix of math nodes` works. The usual one works by setting "execute at begin cell" to roughly `\node[some options] \bgroup` and "execute at end cell" to roughly "\egroup;". This can't work for options because instead of using TeX delimiters, when tikz sees an option it calls a command that has been defined like `\def\getoption[#1]{do stuff}`. Because of this, the `]` character cannot be hidden in a macro. This is why your naive approach didn't work too.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer and the explanation. I thought a bit of a trickier test case, but I think the solution is pretty solid. Passing macros to keys seems to give correct expansions, and any other possible (parsing-related) problem can be worked around by defining a key and using it in the matrix instead. The only less than perverse way to disrupt the macro is inserting some random separators, but that's silly to start with. So I'm really happy with it.

Comment: I edited your answer to keep the first block as you first wrote it, and the second one a bit stricter using `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` and `\pgfutil@gobble` (actually neither is necessary, it's just for good form). Also I've made the example a bit more interesting and added an image.

Comment: I think it is easier to see why `\node\bgroup` works since  path parsing of TikZ doesn't immediately grab the argument when it encounters a brace but waits until the whole context is completed.

Comment: @HoodChatham I just noticed that if the last cell of a row is empty then `\thisshouldnthappen` gets expanded. Working on fixing it.

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin Okay so the problem is that the command that cleans up the `\@nil` is `\matrix@ofnodekeys@start@cell`, but it only deletes it when it's called at the beginning of the last cell. However, if the last cell is empty, instead the `execute at empty cell` command is called, and this command doesn't clean up the \@nil. Unfortunately the `execute at empty cell` command is called inside an extra pair of braces and cannot scan for the `\\ ` like `execute at begin cell` does.

Comment: The solution is to make the `\@nil` into a no-op. The only reason to make it an error is for debugging purpose anyways, and there is no specific harm caused by its evaluation. I'll make the edit above.

Comment: @HoodChatham Just fyi, I found a reason not to just make the terminator a no-op: empty cells get doubled if at the end of a row. See [a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333705/how-do-i-complete-this-rewriting-of-tikz-matrix-of-nodes-parser).